# Redis or MongoDB in Memory

Tags: database-design, mongodb, redis

I am working on processing of documents and storing their hash in Redis to identify duplicate records and some system files.

Recently we migrated to MongoDB from SQL Server as our primary database.

So now does it make sense to manage both Redis and MongoDB? as we can also run MongoDB in memory?

Comment: Per [Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - Requests for Recommendations?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6487/), we can't recommend specific tools. For example, you have provided no context why any of the mentioned databases would be good/bad in your scenario and what your goals and limitations are. Without context, it's not even clear that an in-memory DB would have any advantages at all. E.g. in-memory is good if your latency requirements are tighter than your budget, and when durability is unnecessary.

Comment: i have mentioned my goal and limitations. goal is to manage duplicate and system files. limitation is to manage multiple databases. so with that context inmemory databse have advantage of performance.

Comment: I'm trying to nudge you towards clarifying for yourself what your specific and measurable goals are. Example: if every extra 1ms of latency costs $1000/month, and a MongoDB solution would add 2ms latency, but having a single DB would save $700 for hosting & administration, then it's clearly not a good idea to stop using Redis. I've mentioned durability because MongoDB's in-memory mode doesn't have it (!). And while in-memory is obviously faster than reading from disk, all DBs cache hot data such as indexes. You might not need low-latency access to cold data, enabling cost optimization.

Comment: latency is not that much of a concern as these db is being used by microservices. so they can wait.